# Wordpress - loading custom css on index.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, layout

i am trying to load custom layout style for index.php. My theme is called kendo and i am trying to pull some custom stylesheets in functions.php

Stylesheets work separately (if i delete one line for example), but they keep overriding each other. Is something wrong with my code?

```
function kendo_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kendo-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    if (is_page_template('index'))  {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'kendo-layout-style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/no-sidebar.css' );
    }
    if (!is_page_template('index')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'kendo-layout-style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/content-sidebar.css' );
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong parameter for `is_page_template` hook. Use full template filename with extension. `index.php` not `index`.

[See function is_page_template reference.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)

This was the possible issues. A sample code:

```
/*Add Hook*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kendo_scripts' );

/*Define the callback*/
function kendo_scripts() {

   wp_enqueue_style( 'kendo-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), null, 'all' );

   if ( is_page_template( 'index.php' ) )  {

      wp_enqueue_style( 'kendo-layout-style1', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );

   } else {

      wp_enqueue_style( 'kendo-layout-style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/content-sidebar.css', array(), null, 'all' );
   }
}
```

See also 2 reference answers in StackExchange: [one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166185/what-is-the-correct-way-to-enqueue-multiple-css-files-in-wp) and [two](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136655/wp-enqueue-style-for-plugin-with-multiple-stylesheets)

Comment: Thank you, i tried both with index and index.php parameter, but still it didnt work. I have solved the problem by using different css classes, which is maybe not ideal, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't adding this to header.php be easier...

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/stylesheet1.css"/>
<?php } else { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/stylesheet2.css"/>
<?php } ?>
```